# Is there a way to create shell scripts (.command files) for MacOS that do not require updating the permissions?

Tags: macos, shell, permissions, command

I have a shell script (.command) that gets created every day to install the latest build. The .bat works fine on Windows machines but on MacOS I have to go into Terminal and type `chmod u+x [filename.command]` before I can run it.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Usually, it'd be up to the process that creates the script file to set its permissions. How is the file being created?

Comment: Also, how exactly do you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the script as argument of a shell, eg. `sh /path/to/script.sh`, `csh /path/to/script.sh`, `zsh /path/to/script.sh` (the same for almost every UNIX shell). The script doesn't even need to start with shebang (#!/bin/sh or similar), even the name of the script is completely irrelevant (as it has to, AFAIR, for DOS)